# PTIJ: Why would blindness cause ignorance?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

According to the gemara, as explained in the kitzur, 142:6

> חַיָב אֱנָשׁ לְבַסּוּמֵי בַּפּוּרְיָא עַד דְּלָא יֵדַע בֵּין אָרוּר הָמָן לְבָרוּךְ מָרְדְּכָי. וְלַפָּחוֹת יִשְׁתֶּה יוֹתֵר מֵהֶרְגֵּלוֹ

This strange combination of Hebrew and Aramaic (Puria for Purim, Sumey for [Suma](https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90)) leads to the following translation:

"A man is obligated to become blind on Purim until he doesn't know [the difference] between 'cursed is Haman' and 'blessed is Mordechai'. At least he must drink more than his legs (others say "more than he does on his holiday")"

Why would not being able to see lead to not knowing the difference between two characters in the megillah?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: [That's not what it means!!!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36193/4794)

Comment: The question title doesn't really match what your asking. "cause ignorance" is not quite the same as having the ability to distinguish between two people. Can you edit this to clarify?

Comment: You used Haman both times so I changed the second one to Mordechai. If that’s not what you meant please re-edit.

Comment: "Why would not being able to see lead to not knowing the difference between two characters in the megillah?" I would think this was obvious.

Comment: @Alex actually, rosends just started a little early and already fulfilled his obligation.